# Icloud copy get an Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512

Tags: ios, icloud

When I copy a file from local application to iCloud, the file is copied but I got this error :
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)"

Here is the code

```
NSString *source = [tagsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:current_Group_Name];
source = [source stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:source];

dispatch_queue_t q_default;
q_default = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(q_default, ^(void) {

    fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSURL *ubiq = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    if (ubiq) {
        NSURL *groupURL = [tagsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:current_Group_Name];
        NSError *error= nil;
        NSURL *destinationURL = [groupURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        [fileManager setUbiquitous:YES
                     itemAtURL:sourceURL
                     destinationURL:destinationURL
                     error:&error];
                if (error != nil)
                { NSLog( @"Error > %@",error);
                 [self displayError:NSLocalizedString(@"XMP file not saved in iCloud.", @"") withReason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",NSLocalizedString(@"Error code : ", @""),[error code]]];}

    dispatch_queue_t q_main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(q_main, ^(void) {
    });
});
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here, please keep us posted.

Comment: You should not try to look at `error` if you are not sure that `setUbiquitous` failed. I may not be related but you code should be `if (![fileManager blahblahblah]) NSLog(blahblahblah);`

Answer (score 1):

this only happens for me on IOS6 devices, the strange thing is that it actually seems the save, when I load my save data, the only issue is that if I remove the app and then redownload it, it seems to wipe the icloud data

Comment: After investigation the technical support ask me to file a bug report. Wait and see.

Comment: Can you link to that bug report? I'm seeing this too, and would like to monitor that bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the same code

```
setUbiquitous:YES
                 itemAtURL:sourceURL
                 destinationURL:destinationURL
                 error:&error];
```

for moving file to iCloud and at that time  i also got the same error, but i finally solved that by a small change in the code like this

```
[[[NSFileManager alloc]init]setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:ubiquitousPackage destinationURL:localurl2 error:&error];
```